# How can you add an API as a distribution of a Dataset - http://schema.org/Dataset

Tags: schema.org

According to the description of a distribution ([DataDownload](http://schema.org/DataDownload)) it refers to a file.

> A downloadable form of this dataset, at a specific location, in a specific format.

What if your dataset is distributed within a service or an API? You can think of [Open311 Inquiry](http://wiki.open311.org/Inquiry_v1) for instance. Or let's say that a very huge dataset is available for download but also within an JSON API to allow search.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do it with schema.org right now.

This was discussed at *public-vocabs@w3.org* and Joshua Shinavier (author of Dataset proposal to schema.org) said that this option is not available now and should be subject of different proposal. Check his [email](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2012Jul/0067.html)

> > 2)  Would it make sense to describe an API on top of a dataset instead of
> >     simply a dataset.
>
> This is a very important question.  It would be reasonable to allow a
>   Dataset distribution to be either a data download, a web service, or a
>   feed, as in DCAT, *if* there were a straightforward mapping to
>   schema.org types and properties.  However, schema.org does not have an
>   equivalent of DCAT's Distribution class (which is a superclass of
>   Download, WebService, and Feed), and I don't even see a proposal for
>   feed or web service types.  That means that in order to allow the
>   distribution property to point to any of the three types of resources,
>   either schema.org would need to allow multiple types in the range of a
>   property, or we would have to add four new types to schema.org just
>   for distributions.  Alternatively, separate properties could be added
>   for feeds and web services.  In any case, two additional types would
>   need to be added to schema.org.  Since those types are relatively
>   fundamental, I suspect they would need to be the subject of other,
>   individual proposals.